# The Sums of the Subsets are Distinct

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

Let $S$ be a set of $n$ positive integers such that no two subsets have the same sum. Prove that $\sum_{a \in S} \frac{1}{a} < 2$.

I have found a paper with a nice proof of the statement by S. J. Benkoski and Paul Erdos http://renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1974-24.pdf

but I'd still like to see an elementary proof.

Comment: One thing to note is that the series $1 + \frac12 + \frac14 +\frac18 +\cdots = 2$, and that $\{1, 2, 4, 8,\ldots\}$ is in some sense the "biggest" set of positive integers such that no two subsets have the same sum (in the sense that you start with $1$, and then you repeatedly add the smallest allowable integer). From this I get the following idea: If $S = \{a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ is sorted in ascending order, is it possible that we must have $a_i \geq 2^i$? I don't know whether it's true, but it's a concrete place to start.

Comment: If $E=\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ is a subset of $S$ with its elements sorted in ascending order, we have $2^n$ subsets of $E$ with the sum of their elements being bounded by $a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n$. By the pigeonhole principle it follows that $a_1+\ldots+a_n\geq 2^n$. Now it shouldn't be difficult to finish.

Comment: Yes I noticed that too but I don't know how to finish from there.

Comment: Here's an almost proof:  From the observation that $a_1+\cdots + a_n \geq 2^n$, we deduce that $a_n \geq 2^n/n$.  The induction hypothesis gives us that this is true for all $n$.  
Then $\sum_{a\in S}1/a \leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n}{2^n} = 2$.  To evaluate this last sum, observe that $1/(1-x) = 1 + x + x^2 + \cdots.$  Differentiate and multiply by $x$ to get $x/(1-x)^2 = x + 2x^1 + 3x^3 + \cdots.$  Plug in $x=1/2$ to get the last sum. The problem is that $1$ is missing from the last sum.  If the bound $a_n \geq 2^n/n$ could be tightened to $2^n/(n-1)$, I think we'd have a nice proof.

Comment: Just found this post. If it's of any interest, that (brilliant) proof can be made elementary by avoiding an evaluation of the integrals: labelling the first as $A$ and the second $B$, then $B-A=-\int_0^1 x^{-1}\log(1-x^2)\,\mathrm{d}x=-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 x^{-1}\log(1-x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ which is $\frac{1}{2}B$ (sub is $x^2\mapsto x$) so $B=2A$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is enough to show that among every other sequence satisfying $\sum_{i=1}^m a_i \geq 2^m - 1$ for every $m$, the sequence $1,2,4,\dots$ maximizes the sum of the reciprocals. Since $1,2,4,\dots$ also satisfies that distinct subset sum property, we're done.

Suppose that $a_1 < a_2 < \dots < a_n$ satisfies $\sum_{i=1}^m a_i \geq 2^m - 1$ for every $m$ and $k$ is the first index where $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i > 2^{k} - 1$. (i.e. $a_k > 2^{k-1}$).

Then there are two cases:

1. If there is no $j > k$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^j a_i = 2^{j} - 1$. Then replace $a_k$ with $a_k - 1$. Since $\sum_{i=1}^m a_k > 2^m-1$ for all $m \geq k$, replacing $a_k$ with $a_k-1$ maintains $\sum_{i=1}^m a_k \geq 2^m-1$ for all $m$. Since $\frac{1}{a_k} < \frac{1}{a_k-1}$, the sum increases.
2. If there is a $j > k$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^j a_i = 2^{j} - 1$ (and suppose $j$ is the smallest such index). Then, replace $a_k$ with $a_k-1$ and $a_j$ with $a_j + 1$. Since $\sum_{i=1}^m a_k > 2^m-1$ for all $k \leq m < j$, replacing $a_k$ with $a_k - 1$ and $a_j$ with $a_j + 1$ maintains the bounds. Since $a_k < a_j$, $\frac{1}{a_k} + \frac{1}{a_j} < \frac{1}{a_k-1} +\frac{1}{a_j+1}$, the sum increases.

Repeat until the sequence is $1,2,4,\dots$. Since $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \dots + \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} < 2$ and the sum $\frac{1}{a_1} + \dots + \frac{1}{a_n}$ increased at each step, then $\frac{1}{a_1} + \dots + \frac{1}{a_n} < 2$.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that any sequence $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ with distinct subset sums has the property that $\sum_{i=1}^ma_i\geq 2^m-1$. I don't know if this fact would otherwise be obvious to every reader.

Comment: True. This is by the pigeonhole principle, as noted in the comment by Jack D'Aurizio. There are $2^m - 1$ distinct nonempty subsets and if each sum is different, the largest sum must be at least as large as $2^m - 1$.